# AX 2012 AIF Outbound - Released Product and Linked data in 1 XML file

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012-r3, aif

I'm on AX 2012 R3 CU10.

I need to export Items data *(Released Products)* in XML format.
But also related data like:

- Translations *(Product > Languages > Translations)*
- Site Specific Order Settings for Sales, Purch and Invent *(Manage inventory >  - Order settings > Site specific order settings)*
- External Item Description *(Sell > Related information > External item description)*
- Product Attributes Data *(Product > Setup > Product attributes)*
- Document Handling *(Product > Attachments > Attachments)*
- etc...

I can make an outbound port with a single Service Operation. That works fine.
However, adding multiple Service Operations to a single port seems to result in one XML file for each Service Operation.
I need a single XML per Released Product.

I have the impression that AIF is designed to handle only 1 single Service Operation per Outbound Port.
And that all the data that you want in a single XML output file, needs to be able to be queried by 1 single AOT Query node.

Does anyone know how to export the data I need in one single XML file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To export all data that you need in one single file you should create new AIF document service. First, create an AOT query that contains the required information. The link below will help you find the tables that you need and create a query.
[How to: Create a Document Query [AX 2012]](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa851589.aspx).
Also you can use the following picture as a hint

[image: Query sample]

Then create AIF service using AIF Document Service Wizard. Please refer the link below for details 
[How to: Create a Service by Using the AIF Document Service Wizard [AX 2012]](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa609947.aspx)

Comment: Well, that's the problem. I cannot fit all the data I need in 1 query. But I still need to output it all in 1 xml file. Is there a possibility to perform extra data retrieval during processing?

Comment: The example above contains all data you asked about: Translations > EcoResProductTranslation;
Site Specific Order Settings for Sales, Purch and Invent > InventTableModule;
External Item Description > CustVendExternalItem;
Product Attributes Data > EcoResAttribute, EcoResValue;
Document Handling  > DocuRef

Comment: If you need to add extra (non database) data to your output XML please check the following link  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/emeadaxsupport/2011/12/08/aif-how-to-add-extra-non-database-field-into-xsd/